# Why isn't my GMaps.js working?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, gmaps.js

I am having trouble getting GMaps.js working, I followed the instructions on https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/basic.html but the map does not appear, I am also getting the error message:

" Uncaught ReferenceError: GMaps is not defined"

in Chrome's developer tools.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q80xqxxo/1/

HTML

```
<div id="map">MAP</div>
```

CSS

```
#map {
height:500px;
width:500px;
background-color:darkblue
```

}

Javascript

```
new GMaps({
div: '#map',
lat: -12.043333,
lng: -77.028333
});
```

Comment: try to give us some more info! be more specific on your problem? we need more details!!

Comment: Thanks - added more details including the error message I am getting in Chrome's developer tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where are you loading in Gmaps.js?

The link in JSFiddle says http://bitsofinternet.com/massif/js/gmaps.js which gives a 404.  Fix that and Gmaps will probably start working

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q80xqxxo/2/)

added `https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/gmaps.js`, probably should copy that to your server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the gmaps.js script

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="YOURPATH/gmaps.js"></script>
```

and document ready?

```
var map;
$(document).ready(function() {
    prettyPrint();
    map = new GMaps({
        div: '#map',
        lat: -12.043333,
        lng: -77.028333
    });
});
```